# Converting lists to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following five lists:

```
a = ['RA CROXE-14156', 'RA CROXE-14084', ]
b = ['CR','ENGINEER_NAME','DESCRIPTION','BINARIES']
c = ['John', 'Mark']
d = ['M4 Hiding Emergency Group from mgr menu', 'M4-NRT: SQLCODE_-11300', ]
e = ['TEL', 'mao.SYM']
```

I need to create a list of dictionaries like this:

```
CRS = [
{
      'CR': 'RA CROXE-14156'
      'ENGINEER_NAME': 'John', 
      'DESCRIPTION': 'M4 Hiding Emergency Group from mgr menu',
      'BINARIES': 'TEL'
},
{  
      'CR': 'RA CROXE-14084'
      'ENGINEER_NAME': 'MARK', 
      'DESCRIPTION': 'M4-NRT: SQLCODE_-11300', 
      'BINARIES': 'mao.SYM'
}
]
```

I need to convert the five lists to a list of dictionaries. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following list/dict comprehensions, using `zip()` and `enumerate()`:

```
>>> CRS = [{b[i]: v for i, v in enumerate(x)} for x in zip(a,c,d,e)]
>>> CRS
[{'CR': 'RA CROXE-14156',
  'ENGINEER_NAME': 'John',
  'DESCRIPTION': 'M4 Hiding Emergency Group from mgr menu',
  'BINARIES': 'TEL'},
 {'CR': 'RA CROXE-14084',
  'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Mark',
  'DESCRIPTION': 'M4-NRT: SQLCODE_-11300',
  'BINARIES': 'mao.SYM'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` with `dict`:

```
a = ['RA CROXE-14156', 'RA CROXE-14084', ]
b = ['CR','ENGINEER_NAME','DESCRIPTION','BINARIES']
c = ['John', 'Mark']
d = ['M4 Hiding Emergency Group from mgr menu', 'M4-NRT: SQLCODE_-11300', ]
e = ['TEL', 'mao.SYM']
result = [dict(zip(b, i)) for i in zip(a, c, d, e)]
```

Output:

```
[{'CR': 'RA CROXE-14156', 'ENGINEER_NAME': 'John', 'DESCRIPTION': 'M4 Hiding Emergency Group from mgr menu', 'BINARIES': 'TEL'}, {'CR': 'RA CROXE-14084', 'ENGINEER_NAME': 'Mark', 'DESCRIPTION': 'M4-NRT: SQLCODE_-11300', 'BINARIES': 'mao.SYM'}]
```